# .htaccess and .php? redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm editing a .htaccess file for redirection from www.oldwebsite.com to www.newwebsite.com + specific redirection for pages.

the following code is working good :

```
RedirectPermanent /page.html http://www.newwebsite.com/newpage.html
```

Where I got problem is when I try to redirect pages ending like this with redirectpermanent :

```
oldpage.php?id=1
```

At this point I get a 404 error back.

I tried another solution that is this code

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   ^id=1$
RewriteRule ^oldpage\.php$ http://www.newwebsite.com/newpage2.html [R=301,L]
```

This is working excepted the browser makes me go to the following link :

```
http://www.newwebsite.com/newpage2.html?id=1
```

Can someone help me with this issue. I would like to use Redirect permanent (doesnt work, same thing with Redirect seeother). I think solution is easy but I don't get a detail I think.

Thanks !!!

Comment: There is small typo in your code, `olpage` instead of `oldpage`.

Comment: Ok but this was just an example its not about typo problem in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `?` at the end of rewriteRule to override query string

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   ^id=1$
RewriteRule ^oldpage\.php$ http://www.newwebsite.com/newpage2.html? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: By the way any other solution than this code to do the same thing ?

Comment: RedirectPermanent and other redirect directives ignore the querystring, so you can't make redirection based on query string with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] method for this..

so,

```
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

header("Location: http://www.newwebsite.com$page");
```

It will redirect **http://www.oldwebsite.com/newpage.html** to **http://www.newwebsite.com/newpage.html**

or instead of **$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']** you can try **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URL']**

Comment: Thank you I'll try the other .htaccess solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to drop the query string, you can use the [QSD flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd).

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   ^id=1$
RewriteRule ^oldpage\.php$ http://www.newwebsite.com/newpage2.html? [R=301,L, QSD]
```

Comment: Good option too. Thanks a lot !